php-fpm: increase debugging info for slow log
I'm using apache 2.4.62 on fedora40 with php-fpm 8.3.11 powering a joomla4 website. I've enabled the php-fpm slow log for my site. However, the information being recorded in the slow log is insufficient to really determine what's causing the problem.
Here are my php-fpm settings for my virtual host:
[webstage]
user = idlls
group = idlls
listen = /run/php-fpm/webstage.sock
listen.backlog = 1000
listen.acl_users = apache,nginx,idlls
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 2783
pm.start_servers = 114
pm.min_spare_servers = 94
pm.max_spare_servers = 148
pm.max_requests = 500
pm.status_path = /status-fpm
ping.path = /ping
access.format = "[%t] %m %{REQUEST_SCHEME}e://%{HTTP_HOST}e%{REQUEST_URI}e %f pid:%p took:%ds mem:%{mega}Mmb cpu:%C%% status:%s {%{REMOTE_ADDR}e|%{HTTP_
USER_AGENT}e}"
slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/webstage-slow.log
request_slowlog_timeout = 4s
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/webstage-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 10G
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/wsdlcache

Here is an example from the slow log for my virtual domain.
[27-Sep-2024 17:07:16]  [pool webstage] pid 662255
script_filename = /var/www/html/index.php
[0x00007f3850614100] clean() /var/www/html/libraries/vendor/joomla/input/src/Input.php:171
[0x00007f3850614060] get() /var/www/html/libraries/vendor/joomla/input/src/Input.php:326
[0x00007f3850613f80] __call() /var/www/html/plugins/content/jfbccontent/jfbccontent.php:271
[0x00007f3850613ec0] getSocialK2ItemViewPosition() /var/www/html/plugins/content/jfbccontent/jfbccontent.php:148
[0x00007f3850613da0] getHTML() /var/www/html/plugins/content/jfbccontent/jfbccontent.php:56
[0x00007f3850613cb0] onContentAfterTitle() /var/www/html/libraries/src/Plugin/CMSPlugin.php:289
[0x00007f3850613c00] Joomla\CMS\Plugin\{closure}() /var/www/html/libraries/vendor/joomla/event/src/Dispatcher.php:486
[0x00007f3850613b50] dispatch() /var/www/html/libraries/src/Application/EventAware.php:111
[0x00007f3850613a70] triggerEvent() /var/www/html/components/com_content/src/View/Category/HtmlView.php:113
[0x00007f3850613900] display() /var/www/html/libraries/src/Cache/Controller/ViewController.php:95
[0x00007f3850613830] get() /var/www/html/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:655
[0x00007f38506136e0] display() /var/www/html/components/com_content/src/Controller/DisplayController.php:121
[0x00007f3850613600] display() /var/www/html/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:693
[0x00007f3850613570] execute() /var/www/html/libraries/src/Dispatcher/ComponentDispatcher.php:143
[0x00007f38506134c0] dispatch() /var/www/html/components/com_content/src/Dispatcher/Dispatcher.php:56
[0x00007f38506133f0] dispatch() /var/www/html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:361
[0x00007f3850613300] renderComponent() /var/www/html/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:208
[0x00007f3850613230] dispatch() /var/www/html/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:249
[0x00007f38506131c0] doExecute() /var/www/html/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:293
[0x00007f3850613130] execute() /var/www/html/includes/app.php:61

Can it be configured to record any query strings or the full URL? The problem is that all Joomla URLs begin with index.php. It appears the query string is not included. Joomla then converts that query string into a search-engine-friendly URL. There's no way to correlate these logs to an actual request. There's also no way of knowing how much longer than my 4s timeout this query took.
